# Using a regular expression to extract text in between BBCode-style tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a text like that

> [CONTENT][SECTION]This is the section C #1[/SECTION][SECTION]This is the section C #2[/SECTION][SECTION]This is the section E #3[/SECTION]

and I try to match each section, including the section tags with that expression :

```
\[SECTION\][^SECTION]+(SECTION\])
```

but the above code does not work because the [^SECTION] is looking in the text between the start and end tags for any character that is not S, E, C, T, I ,O and N

Any idea on how to solve that issue ?

I am using PHP to match the tags and it's contents with preg_match_all(); And I like to match each section one by one, and not all the sections at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\[SECTION\](.*?)\[/SECTION\]
```

I think this is what you want, getting the text for the contents of a single SECTION?

The `?` makes the `*` lazy, so it will only match up to the first `[/SECTION]` from the current one.

---

Example:

```
$input = "[CONTENT][SECTION]This is the section C #1[/SECTION][SECTION]This is the section C #2[/SECTION][SECTION]This is the section E #3[/SECTION]";
var_dump(preg_match_all("(\[SECTION\](.*?)\[/SECTION\])",$input,$m),$m);
```

Result:

```
int(3)
array(2) {
    [0]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>string(43) "[SECTION]This is the section C #1[/SECTION]"
        [1]=>string(43) "[SECTION]This is the section C #2[/SECTION]"
        [2]=>string(43) "[SECTION]This is the section E #3[/SECTION]"
    }
    [1]=>array(3) {
        [0]=> string(24) "This is the section C #1"
        [1]=> string(24) "This is the section C #2"
        [2]=> string(24) "This is the section E #3"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need because I need each section to be matched seperatly. The ony you gave me matching all the sections as one.

Comment: This regex should match each section, one at a time. See my edit for sample code and result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

`\[SECTION\].+?\[\/SECTION\]`

Comment: What is the diference with the Kolink answer ? Again that match all the contents from first opening tag to the last opening tag as one match

Comment: Kolink's better. I tried the expression with preg_match_all and it gives me 3 matches for your given data.